# lazy loading trying to load data that is already loaded from an external function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, lazy-loading

Im using a multi tier aproach, i have an mvc4 project for the Views, a dll proyect for the Busines logic, a dll project for my Data Acces and a dll proyect to my EF5 context(edmx) and entities(.tt). 
i have a "Doctor" class on my .tt, this class also contains a list of "Specialties", as a many to many relation so ef gives me:

```
Doctor---DOCTOR_SPECIALTY-----Specialty
```

un my doctors Data acces class i have a generic function to get a medic and a generic function to get the specialties of a specific doctor , then on my doctor logic class i have a function when i create a doctor and then get the specialties for this doctor using the 2 function on my Data acses layer and return it to my MVC4 aplication.

on my MVC aplication i need to loop the list of specialties using a `foreach` loop, but when y try to acces the doctor_specialty collection i get the next error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

i belive this is because for some reason the aplicattion is traing to lazyloading the data instead of using the collection it already has (i have chk on the debugger that the collection is there and contains the correct data), but i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Include Speciality in your query.
Ex:

```
var query=context.Doctors.Include("Specialities") and so on.
```

Comment: i know that if i do an include on doctor_specialty.scpecialty all will be ok but i want to know why if i get the doctor_specialty on a diferent query, on a diferent context and add it to my doctor object, when i try to read it, a lazy load hapends instead of read the values on the collection

Comment: @EricGS I think what the error is saying is that execution of query has been deferred and your context has been disposed before you are trying to access. You can do greedy loading by .ToList() or disable lazy loading, if that is how you want it.